# Вызов С++ функции из инжектированной в процесс DLL - C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll

Подскажите, каким образом можно вызвать функцию из инжектированной в процесс DLL?

Comment: приведите пжлста минимальный набор кода, что вы подразумеваете под инжектированием в процесс DLL?

Comment: Инжекция предполагает что исходная программа ничего не знает об инжектированой DLL. Поэтому может вызвать, а может не вызвать. Нужно детализировать вопрос.

Comment: для DLL определена точка входа - функция DllMain. С вызова данной функции начинается работа dll. Функция вызывается с параметром DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, когда ваша длл загружается инъекционным процессом. Основной код процесса ничего не знает о вашей длл и вызвать её не сможет (за исключением если ваша длл не подменяет используемые процессом функции других библиотек/кода). Если вы хотите реализовать возможность вызова функций вашей длл извне, то необходимо сделать соотв. интерфейс с использованием IPC. Будьте аккуратны, набор функций, которые могут быть использованы в DllMain ограничен.

Comment: Я имел ввиду загрузку dll функцией LoadLibrary

Comment: вызвать функцию какую именно? Или имеется ввиду как вызвать саму  LoadLibrary? Так на хабре хорошо описано.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы знаете протатип функций хоронящихся в dll, тогда воспользуйтесь модификатором `extern` ([ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern))

```
class ExternTest
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)] 
    public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr h, string m, string c, int type);

    static int Main()
    {
        string myString;
        Console.Write("Enter your message: ");
        myString = Console.ReadLine();
        return MessageBox((IntPtr)0, myString, "My Message Box", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос.